# Вывод данных нескольких таблиц laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Идея такая:

У меня имеется три несвязанных между собой таблицы:

items (товары) - id, name
items_categories - id, item_id, category_id
categories (категории) - id, title

Код Items controller:

```
class ItemsController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {

    //$items = Items::all();
    $items = DB::table('items')
    ->select('items.id','items.name','categories.title')
    ->join('items_categories', 'items.id', '=', 'items_categories.item_id')
    ->join('categories', 'items_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->get();
    return view('items.index', [
      'items' => $items,
    ]);
  }
```

Так вот в чем суть, один товар может иметь несколько категорий и я никак не могу вывести в таблицу так, чтобы товар не повторялся. Пока у меня сделано таким образом:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>Название товара</th>
        <th>Категория</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($items as $item)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        <td>
                {{ $item->title }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
  </table>
```

По идее во второй ячейке нужен еще один цикл, который будет еще строки создавать и выводит категории, но так и не получается.
В дальнейшем мне требуется сделать еще и редактирование, удаление по этим таблицам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вам накидал простенький пример двух таблиц, с таблицей отношений. Старался использовать ваши имена таблиц, чтобы было янснее. Безусловно всей вашей структуры я не могу знать.

Category:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {}
```

Item

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model {}
```

ItemCategory (модель отношений)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ItemCategory extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'item_categories', 'category_id');
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'item_categories', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Как пользоваться:

```
    $item = new ItemCategory();
    $items = $item->with('category', 'item')->where(['item_id' => 1])->get();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $category = $item->category;
        $item = $item->item;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, более менее разобрался, но все равно у меня есть проблема, не получается вывести эти данные.  То есть в цикле foreach такое - `$category->title` или такое `$item->name` выдает undefined property.

Comment: это значит, что по вашему условию, нет результатов попробуйте сделать так `$items = $item->with('category', 'item')->get();`, там самым вы получите все данные из таблицы связей и в свою очередь отношения со связанными таблицам