# Как получить все пробежки членов клуба?

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

Имеется: Club.php User.php
club_users связь М:М

Scampers.php (пробежки)
User(id)-Scamper(id,user_id) связь 1:М

Как получить все пробежки участников клуба?

User relation:

```
public function scampers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Scamper::class);
}
```

Club relation:

```
public function scampers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Scamper::class, User::class);
}
```

Я понимаю, что проблема именно в club.scampers, но не знаю как правильно сделать.

Comment: [посмотрите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848161/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-laravel/848364#848364)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас всё сделано правильно, если бы все связи были 1:M. Но есть одно НО — в Laravel не работает метод hasManyThrough при работе со связями М:М. Проблеме уже больше 4 лет и каждый решает её по-своему: от обхода в цикле связи M:M и затем сбора всех в одну коллекцию, до других методов. Относительно недавно на эту тему вышла очередная [статья, проясняющая возможность получать данные hasManyThrough даже через полиморфные взаимосвязи](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db).