# Laravel конструктор запросов

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Всем доброго времени суток. Когда то написал запрос с помощью query builder Laravel. Но вот недавно столкнулся с задачей сделать мультиязычность, подключил трейт translatable. И столкнулся с задачей переписать все запросы с query builder на eloquent. Простые запросы переписал без проблем. Возникла сложность с более габаритным запросом где несколько join и много условий.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно переписать данный запрос:

```
$query = DB::table('teachers as t')->select(
        't.id', 't.firstname', 't.price', 't.created_at', 't.experience', 't.image',
        'c.name AS cytyName', 'r.name AS ratingName', 's.name AS subjectName',
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.name SEPARATOR ", ") AS levelName')

    )
        ->leftJoin('subjects as s', 't.subject_id', '=', 's.id')
        ->leftJoin('ratings as r', 't.rating_id', '=', 'r.id')
        ->leftJoin('cyties as c', 't.cyty_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->leftJoin('levels_teachers as lt', 't.id', '=', 'lt.teacher_id')
        ->leftJoin('levels as l', 'lt.level_id', '=', 'l.id')
        ->leftJoin('trainings_teachers as tt', 't.id', '=', 'tt.teacher_id')
        ->leftJoin('trainings as tr', 'tt.training_id', '=', 'tr.id');

    if($subjectsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('t.subject_id', $subjectsIds);
    }
    if($ratingsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('t.rating_id', $ratingsIds);
    }
    if($cytiesIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('t.cyty_id', $cytiesIds);
    }
    if($levelsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('lt.level_id', $levelsIds);
    }
    if($trainingsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('tt.training_id', $trainingsIds);
    }

    switch ($sortIds)
    {
        case self::rating:
            $query->orderBy('r.name');
            break;
        case self::minprice:
            $query->orderBy('t.price', 'DESC');
            break;
        case self::maxprice:
            $query->orderBy('t.price');
            break;
        case self::exp:
            $query->orderBy('t.experience', 'DESC');
            break;
    }

    $query->groupBy('t.id');
    $list = $query->get();

    return $list;
```

Набросал такой  запрос, но фильтровать связи многие ко многим, не совсем понятно как правильно сделать.

```
$query = $this->with([
        'ratings',
        'levels',
        'trainings',
        'subjects',
        'cyties',            
    ]);

    if($subjectsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('subject_id', $subjectsIds);
    }
    if($ratingsIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('rating_id', $ratingsIds);
    }
    if($cytiesIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('cyty_id', $cytiesIds);
    }
    if($levelsIds)
    {
        //многие ко многим
    }
    if($trainingsIds)
    {
        //многие ко многим
    }

    switch ($sortIds)
    {
        case self::rating:
            // тут не совсем понятно как вытащить имя с другой таблицы
            break;
        case self::minprice:
            $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
            break;
        case self::maxprice:
            $query->orderBy('price');
            break;
        case self::exp:
            $query->orderBy('experience', 'DESC');
            break;
    }

    $query->groupBy('id');
    $list = $query->get();

    return $list;
```

Comment: Попробуйте `whereHas('relation', function ($query) {
    $query->where('column', $value);
})` или `with(['relation' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('column', $value);
    }])`

Comment: я [писал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848161/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-laravel) в рамках другого вопроса, надеюсь вам поможет