# Как получить все зависимости от объекта в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, laravel, postgresql

У меня приложение на Laravel, использую базу данных pgsql. Пусть есть модель "Фотография", она хранится в соответствующей таблице базы данных. Её через `foreign key` используют другие части приложения, например, она может быть выставлена аватаркой пользователя или использоваться в статье.

Моя цель в следующем - при попытке удалить фотографию я хочу выдавать примерно такую информацию: *"Нельзя удалить фотографию, так как она используется: 1) Как фото профиля у такого-то пользователя; 2) В статье такой-то"*. То есть мне нужно найти все использования определенного объекта в других таблицах.

Очевидно, что я могу просто перебрать все возможные места использования, но мне не очень нравится это решение. Второй вариант - парсить детали исключения, которое кидает база при попытке удаления объекта со связями... Но формат исключения может изменится и тогда мой скрипт перестанет работать.

Есть ли какой-то правильный и элегантный метод это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете организовать модель сущности "Фотография" со связями, как я это описал в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848161/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-laravel/848364#848364), таким образом, за счет организации связей между сущностями, вы будете знать, что нужно удалить, перед удалением основной сущности. Минус этого подхода в том, данных из БД дергается больше, что логично.